# Display datatable in ListView control

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, data-binding, datatable

How to display a DataTable in a ListView control in WPF?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
listView.ItemsSource = dataTable.DefaultView;
```

Comment: That will display `System.Data.DataRowView` for every row in the table, and nothing else.  It's necessary to define a view and columns in the `ListView.`

Answer (score 7):

[image]

If you want a ListView like above,
and if your DataTable has 3 columns with name "Date", "PCName", "Price" then between your 
 tags add following code:

```
<ListView.View>
   <GridView>
     <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Date}"
                     Header="Date"
                     Width="100"/>
     <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=PCName}"
                     Header="Computer No."
                     Width="100"/>
     <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Price}"
                     Header="Amount (Tk)"
                     Width="100"/>
   </GridView>
</ListView.View>
```

Comment: The rows are not able to select when using gridview in listview

Answer (score 1):

****Convert listview to datatable in c#****
 Just iterate the entire listview table.
Here is the code,

```
private DataTable ConvertList_To_Datatable(ListView lvDetails)
       {
           DataTable dtTable = new DataTable("ExportToPdf");
           if (lvDetails.Items.Count < 1)
           {
               return dtTable;
           }
           else
           {
               for (int ncount = 0; ncount <= lvDetails.Columns.Count-1; ncount++)
               {
                   DataColumn dtColumn =new DataColumn(lvDetails.Columns[ncount].Text);
                   dtTable.Columns.Add(dtColumn);
               }
           }          
           for (int nRowCount = 0; nRowCount <= lvDetails.Items.Count - 1; nRowCount++)
           {
               DataRow dtRow = dtTable.NewRow();
               for (int nItem = 0; nItem <=lvDetails.Items[nRowCount].SubItems.Count - 1; nItem++)
               {                    
                   dtRow[lvDetails.Columns[nItem].Text] = lvDetails.Items[nRowCount].SubItems[nItem].Text;

               } dtTable.Rows.Add(dtRow);

           } return dtTable;

       }
```

Just try this .It works
If any dout .U can reach me at
prinsuyakob20@gmail.com

Comment: This one has me scratching my head.  Why, instead of displaying what is in a datatable in a listview, which is what is asked, do you offer a means to fetch the data of an already populated listview into that datatable?