# Dynamic Searchbox within Listview

Tags: c#, listview, search

I have a Listview that contains several items from a DB, and I have a Searchbox that filters this Listview based on the characters typed in the Searchbox.

This all works great and was done using help from "TaW" the link here : [How to search listview's items with textbox in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52420520/how-to-search-listviews-items-with-textbox-in-c-sharp)

First: I've stored the full set of items in a class level variable:

```
List<ListViewItem> allItems = new List<ListViewItem>();
```

Then I've filled it after the full set of items has been added:

```
allItems.Clear();
allItems.AddRange(listView1.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>());
```

Then I've coded the TextChanged event of our filterTextbox; here I always use the full set of data:

```
private void filterbox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listView1.Items.Clear();   // clear all items we have atm
    if (filterbox.Text == "")
    {
        listView1.Items.AddRange(allItems.ToArray());  // no filter: add all items
        return;
    }
    // now we find all items that have a suitable text in any subitem/field/column
    var list = allItems.Cast<ListViewItem>()
                       .Where( x => x.SubItems
                                     .Cast<ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem>()
                                     .Any(y => y.Text.Contains(filterbox.Text)))
                       .ToArray();
    listView1.Items.AddRange(list);  // now we add the result
}
```

However I've noticed that this treats upper and lowercase as separate things, so if I search for "Web" it would filter all entries with the word "Web", but not those with "WEB" or "web".

How can I make this so it simply works based on the letters rather than the case as I don't care.
I'd want my list filtered so it showed all 3 entries - "Web", "WEB" and "web"?

I feel I need some sort of conversion 'ToUpper' or 'ToLower' but I'm not really sure where to put this in the code I have.

Thank you,

Comment: If you want us to help you fix code you already have, show us the code. Even if it's exactly the same, don't make us go somewhere else to see it. Show us all that's relevant and only what's relevant.